# "the day at which"?

Tags: word-usage

Is this sentence right:

"Thursday will be the day **at which** we're going to bid farewell to her"?

Most people use it like "the hour of the day at which".

Comment: That "at which" sounds completely superfluous to me, as does the future aspect.  You can just say "Thursday is the day we bid farewell to her."

Comment: Can you clarify how people could use "the day at which" to mean "the hour of the day at which"? (I'm assuming by "our" you mean hour".) I don't see how it could mean that in your example sentence, or in any other context that I can think of.

Comment: Word of the day: *when*.

Comment: @suməlic Sorry it was a typing mistake, I meant "hour", Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, twice over.

"At which" should be "on which" but even "on which" isn't necessary.

"Thursday will be the day on which we bid farewell to her" would strictly be more formally correct.

"Thursday will be the day we bid farewell to her" would be perfectly acceptable to most listeners.